# CorePlot symbolsTouch prevents from dragging a plotSpace

Tags: ios, core-plot

```
-(void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot
         plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
         withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
```

I'm using this method to implement annotation creating on core plot. However it gets called right when a user touches the symbol. So that touch is being swallowed after that, and if the user wanted to scroll a plotspace and accidentally touch began on a symbol, the user wont be able to scroll, because the annotation would appear. 
Is there a way to track if there was a complete touch on a symbol? Like a tap gesture?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been working on the event handling recently on the [release-2.0](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/tree/release-2.0) branch. We added touch down and touch up events for each item that has a "wasSelected" delegate method (plots, axes, and legends). The "wasSelected" methods now fire only if the down and up events occur on the same element. You can still scroll as long as the delegate does not implement the touch down methods.

Comment: Thanks i will look into it. I have one more question though.
Im using custom labels for X axis - they are dates, buy with different steps between them...could be 1 minute could be weeks. 
When there is large amount of data and i use plotSpace method scaleToFitPlots, labels start to overlay each other obviously, and it starts to lag. I tried to relabel in plotSpace delegate method - willChangeRange but it becomes even more laggy. 
What i want is some kind of labelingPolicy automatic but with my data, so there will be 4-5 labels on the x axis at a time.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Instead of custom labels, can you use a `labelFormatter` to format the automatic labels? Core Plot includes `CPTCalendarFormatter` and `CPTTimeFormatter` for working with dates or you could create a custom `NSFormatter` subclass if you have more specific formatting needs. If you need to keep the custom labels, don't create new labels every time the plot range changes. Only make new labels when the changed range crosses some threshold you set based on the size of the graph and the number and size of the labels.

Comment: i think i cant use formatter cos intervals between dates are not the same, or i can?

Comment: Use the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyLocationsProvided` labeling policy and place tick locations where you need them; they don't have to be evenly spaced. The axis will use the `labelFormatter` to format labels at each tick location.

Comment: Thats's not what i want :( I want so there is only 4-5 custom labels on x axis at a time.

Comment: Then use `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone` and create only the labels you want. Custom labels don't have to be placed at the tick locations.

Comment: thanks. where can i find libCorePlotCocoaTouch.a for release 2.0?

Comment: There isn't one yet. Pull the latest code from [GitHub](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot), open the iOS framework project, and build the "Universal Library" target.

Comment: it says build succeeded but where can i find an .a file?

Comment: Thank you very much! You are very helpful :)
I found a bug though, when i create an annotation with 
style.fontSize = 12.0f;
style.fontName = @"HelveticaNeue-Medium";
the whole string does not fit on the annotation, there is 3 lines in the string and only 2 visible.
but if i use 14.0 fontSize, it would be ok, all 3 lines are visible. 
And thats not just those 12 and 14 sizes, 15 is not working too etc...

Comment: Please post bug reports on the Core Plot [issue tracker](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues).